# PlayOnLinux won't open; cannot find curl from cURL

Tags: installation

Every time I try to open Play On Linux I keep getting this message:

```
Play On Linux cannot find curl (from cURL)
You need to install it to continue
```

but I can't seem to find where I am supposed to get this `cUrl` anywhere.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install curl` on a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Open a commandline by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and type:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Press enter and type your password. There will be no characters shown.

When prompted, hit yes.

Then close/reopen PoL.